# Check equality $\int_\Omega (u_{xx}+u_{yy}) \, dx \, dy=\int_\ell \nabla u| n \, d\ell$ where $\ell=\partial \Omega$, $n$-normal vector

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In this case, $u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\Omega=\{x^2+y^2 \le 2020\}.$ So, if $$u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \Rightarrow u_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \Rightarrow u_{xx}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x^2(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$u_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Rightarrow u_{yy}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-y^2(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{x^2+y^2}$$ Then $$\int_{\Omega} \frac{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy = \\ 2\int_\Omega \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2(x^2+y^2)}} \, dx \, dy = \\ 2\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy=\left[r^2=x^2+y^2  \right] \Rightarrow \\ 2\int_{\Omega}\frac{r}{r^2} \, dr \, d\phi$$

I think this is incorrect and I don't know how to proceed further. It is given that $x^2+y^2 \le 2020$, so maybe I can take bounds for $r$ from 0 to 2020? Don't know about $\phi$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up right away in that
$$\begin{align}u_{xx}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\right)=(1)(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}+(x)\left(-\frac12\right)(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}(2x)\\
&=\frac{x^2+y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\end{align}$$
It should be anticipated that
$$u_{yy}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
So that
$$\nabla^2u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
You could have gotten this also from
$$\nabla^2f(r)=\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial r}\right)$$
In $2$ dimensions. Then
$$\int\int_{\Omega}\nabla^2u\,d^2A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{2020}}\frac1r\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\sqrt{2020}$$
On $\partial\Omega$,
$$\vec r=\sqrt{2020}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$$,
$$d\vec r=\sqrt{2020}\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle\,d\theta$$
So
$$\hat n\,d\ell=\sqrt{2020}\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta\times\langle0,0,1\rangle=\sqrt{2020}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta$$
Also
$$\vec\nabla u=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle$$
So
$$\oint_{\partial\Omega}\vec\nabla u\cdot\hat n\,d\ell=\int_0^{2\pi}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle\cdot\sqrt{2020}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta=2\pi\sqrt{2020}$$